# How do I transform(For deployment) a bunch of Sql files?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, transformation

I have a small Windows Form application that I have continuously developed for about two years. Because my boss keeps(Changing) requirements that make my sql queries very complex, my EntityFramework 6 (Linq & Lamda)  queries have slowed painfully down. I have tweeked them as much as I can (by making my fetch data methods Async/Await and only selecting the fields I need, etc..). What I have found was that using SQL directly (as in SqlConnection() and SqlCommands()) is much faster for complex Sql queries.
I have a few that use two different databases in the same complex query. For example:

```
SELECT
strStock,
IM.strMLILocation,
IM.strDescription,
IM.curLastCost,
(IM.decQuantityOnHand - (SELECT
    SUM(decQuantityShipped)
FROM NewCats.dbo.ZSA_TransactionDetail 
WHERE strStock = IM.strStock)
) AS decQuantityOnHand,
(SELECT
    SUM(PD.decQuantityRemaining)
FROM CATX.dbo.PO_TransactionDetail AS PD
WHERE PD.strStockItem = IM.strStock)
AS decQuantityOnBO
FROM CATX.dbo.IN_Master AS IM;
```

I use SlowCheetah to Transform my App.Config for Debug and Release. Which is fine for EntityFramework Connection Strings.. But I cannot transform Query.sql files (Yes, they are content and read in at run time)
So my problem is how do I transform a bunch of Sql files? If I write an exe or batch file (Pre-Build) to parse them (Search and Replace Database Names) should I use the files in the Project Directory or the Output Directory (~/bin/Release/).

VS 2015
InstallShield LE 2015
Framework 4.6

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I managed to solve my problem from @KiwiPiet comment.

I created a Synonym on each server with the same name but pointing to the correct Table and Database on each server.

Then modified my sql scripts to call to the Synonym instead.

If you wouldn't mind @KiwiPiet, post your comment as an answer so I can credit you.

Cheers,

Comment: Why don't you use a placeholder for the database names?
Then at run-time replace the placeholder with the correct database name.